# Rails and javascript?: fetch select_tag value in the index page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html-select

I'd like to build a super simple store using RoR and found a great example in the 'Agile Web Developmenet with Rails' book. What I have is a list of products on the store's index page and for each product a button to add the product to the cart. Like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.name %><br />
    <%= button_to 'Order', add_to_cart_store_index_path(:id => product), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to do is to add a small dropdown menu for the user to select the number of items that they would like to order:

```
<%= select_tag("quantity[#{product.id}]", options_for_select(['1', '2', '3', '4'], '1')) %>
```

Clicking on the button needs to pass the selected value form the select_tag menu.

```
<%= button_to 'Order', add_to_cart_store_index_path(:id => product, :quantity => ?????), :remote => true %>
```

I'm new to programming, but I think I need javascript/jQuery for this, something like #quantity[#{product.id}].val(), but I can't get it to work.

I hope you can help with this. If you see a better way to implement this, let me know as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to implement the add to cart button this way I would make it a form though so that it all works together and submits the quantity without writing javascript.

```
<%= form_tag add_to_cart_store_index_path(:id => product), :method => :post do %>
  <%= select_tag :quantity, options_for_select(['1', '2', '3', '4'], '1' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add to cart' %>
<% end %>
```

As a side note it may be a good exercise to learn programming by creating your own simple store following your book, but if you intend to do anything more complex or production worthy it would save you a lot of time to try something like Spree http://github.com/spree/spree as a solution rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks JDutil, at first it seemed a bit strange to me to have many "mini-forms" on one page, but this actually makes perfect sense. I see your point about Spree, it's a beautiful product, but too complex for my needs.